# Create GitHub issue from Freshdesk (via email)

Tags: email, github, integration, github-api, freshdesk

We are currently using Freshdesk for our customer support and GitHub for our code. On receiving a bug or an improvement feature request via Freshdesk, we would like to forward that ticket (with all the details + screenshots) to an email in GitHub so an issue is created automatically on GitHub. That would save us a manual entry.

Look forward to an advice on this or a better solution.

NOTE: Had come across https://zapier.com/zapbook/gmail/github/72/create-github-issue-email , but we would prefer a direct interaction without a third-party app in between.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Creating an issue to GitHub wouldn't be done by "sending an email", but only by using the [GitHub v3 issue API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/) (like [this script, for example, to migrate issues to GitHub](https://gist.github.com/nidico/3778347))

That means in your case having a trigger on FreshDesk (or an ["Observer" to call a webhook](https://support.freshdesk.com/support/articles/132589-using-webhooks-in-the)) which would parse the ticket and create the appropriate bug report on GitHub.

From the [Observer/WebHook help page](https://support.freshdesk.com/support/articles/132589-using-webhooks-in-the):

> Webhooks also come handy when you want to trigger an action in an external application or tool (as well as some updates that the Observer can't perform, like update time entry on a ticket or add a note to a ticket)

You would manage that webhook locally on your side, and that callback would in turn call the right GitHub API commands to create the GitHub issue.

Comment: Cool, thank you! I checked your links and I think this is exactly what I was looking for. Just wanted to make sure it's working for me before marking it as 'accepted answer' - will get back.

Can't up-vote the answer (I do not have the reputation score yet).

Answer (score 4):

We had similar needs and built a very simple tool to let anyone in the team send/forward emails to create GitHub issues. We were using it internally at first so that non engineering team members didn't have to go to GitHub to create issues. We just made it available to anyone (and free). It supports attachments.

You can find it at https://fire.fundersclub.com.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. OP said "would prefer a direct interaction without a third-party app in between."

Comment: hi @alex, this is actualy super interesting for me, but unfurtunatley I can not make the website work - after the login I just see an empty page "Choose a Repository". Is this still maintained and available. Thx a lot

Comment: @alex, just managed to do it - thx! It was just not clear, that I need to give manually read access for the fire-bot github user.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. OP said "would prefer a direct interaction without a third-party app in between."